# Como Criar uma comunicação entre dois clientes via servidor usando socket

Tags: python, python-2.7, socket

```
import socket
from threading import Thread
def client(h, p):

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)  # IPv4,tipo de socket
    s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

    while True:
        try:
            s.connect((h, p))
            break
        except Exception as e:
            pass

    print "Conectou"
    msg = ''
    while msg != "Fim":
        msg = raw_input("Entre com a mensagem: ")
        s.sendall(msg)# Envia dados
        var = s.recv(1024)
        print var
    s.close()  # Termina conexao
    print "Fechou a conexao"
if __name__ == '__main__':

h2 = raw_input("Entre com o IP do servidor remoto:")
port2= input("Entre com a porta do servidor remoto:")
client(h2,port2)


# Criando o codigo do servidor
import socket
from threading import Thread
L=[]

def ConversaSimultanea(a,b):
    mensagem = ""
    while mensagem != "Fim":
        print "entrou no loop da conversa"
        mensagem = L[a].recv(5000)
        if not mensagem:
            break
        L[b].sendall(mensagem)
    conn.close()

#h = raw_input("Entre com o IP do Servidor local: ")
#port = input("Entre com a Porta do Servidor local: ")

h = '127.0.0.1'
port = int('40000')

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)  # IPv4,tipo de socket
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.bind((h, port))  # liga o socket com IP e porta
s.listen(1)  # espera chegar pacotes na porta especificada
print "server escutando"

for i in range(2):
    print "esperando o primeiro cliente conectar-se"
    conn, addr = s.accept()  # as variaveis conn a addr sao preenchidas pela funcao accept
    L.append(conn)
    print "conectei e appendei o primeiro cliente"
t1 = Thread(target=ConversaSimultanea, args=(1,0,)).start()
t2 = Thread(target=ConversaSimultanea, args=(0,1,)).start()
```

Esses dois códigos estão funcionando em parte. O problema que estou tendo é que para um cliente enviar uma mensagem ele tem que ter recebido uma mensagem.
PS: Para que ele funcione tem que rodar o código do servidor primeiro uma vez, e, depois o do cliente duas vezes, e estou usando o Windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

esse é o momento em que você descobre *porque* as pessoas não fazem isso ordinariamente. mandar uma mensaem de teste via sockets é simples - com código como o acima. ter uma implementação completa de um chat depende várias outras coisas: é um sistema completo, você vai precisar ter um "loop principal" separado em thread ou com async, em vez de travar nas chamadas `recv` do socket, etc...

É só olhar seu código e ver que ele faz exatamente o que você mandou - e daí perceber que ele não pode, nem de longe ser um chat genérico: o seu código no servidor está "hardcoded" (isso é, fixo no código do programa) para só mandar mensagens do cleint "a" para o cliente "b", mas nunca vai fazer o contrário.

Em suma, tem bastante trabalho pela frente, e você vai precisar aprender bastante enquanto faz isso. Se realmente estiver a fim, vai valer a pena no final, mas não é só uma ou duas linhas de código que faltam aí.

Então, só pra dar algumas dicas de que caminho seguir, mas seria perto de um livro pra explicar tudo. Então, em código como:

```
while msg != "Fim":
    msg = raw_input("Entre com a mensagem: ")
    s.sendall(msg)# Envia dados
    var = s.recv(1024)
    print var
```

Fica fácil ver que só depois que alguém responder o input você vai executar o método `recv`, e só então receber uma mensagem (se vai receber alguma). Por outro lado, depois do input, enquanto não chegar nenhuma mensagem do socket, o programa vai ficar parado esperando o retorno do método `s.recv`.

A única forma de resolver esse tipo de coisa é ter um "loop principal" de controle que não chame diretamente as funções bloqueantes: que são as de receber dados do socket e de receber dados do teclado.

Se você fizer seu programa no modo gráfico, por exemplo, com "tkinter", já vai resolver 80% dos problemas: você vai ter um a area de texto para o chat, e uma entrada de texto, num controle separado, para escrever a mensagem. Nao vai ter problema de misturaro que a pessoa está digitando com mensagens que chegaram, e ele controla a entrada de texto de forma assincrona - além do que, tendo uma janela, você pode convidar seus amigos e parentes para experimentarem seu programa que não vai ficar só no terminal.

No modo texto você tem que fazer tudo "na mão" mesmo. O jeito mais fácild e começar, mas nem o "mais correto para terminar" e talvez nem o mais simples, vai ser usando threads. Uma "thread". (Para uma form a"mais correta, veja o módulo `selectors` da biblioteca padrão do Python. O exemplo que tem lá é para sockets, mas você pode registrar `sys.stdin` para ser notificado quando o usuário digitar algo, antes de ter que chamar o input)

Porque vou falar de thread então? Por que é um conceito que você tem que entender, para entender melhor sistemas grandes depois - mesmo que eles não usem "threads" explicitamente, vão emular seu comportamento de alguma forma.

cada "thread" vai ser como um programa separado, que roda "ao mesmo tempo" que seu programa principal. Desta forma, você pode ter uma thread esperando o "input", uma thread esperando o "recv", e uma terceira thread prinipal que poderia imprimir tudo.

Para comunicar os dados entre as threads, você pode usar uma fila do tipo threading.Queue(), Mas no caso dessa primeira versão mais simples, você pode ter ambas as threads fazendo "tudo o que precisam" direto, sem trocar dados entre si. (Um programa de chat esquizofrênico);

O seu "cliente multi-threaded" poderia ficar mais ou menos assim: 
(Python 3- Alias, mude para Python 3. Python 2 é do milênio passado, o que você está fazendo com isso?). A única diferença é que é necessário decodificar o texto para bytes ao envia-lo para o socket, e vice-versa. Alem do "print" e "input" mais sensatos.

```
import socket
from threading import Thread
import time

def recebe_mensagens(socket_):
    while True:
        msg = socket_.recv(1024)
        if not(len(msg)):
            break
        print(msg.decode("utf-8"))
    print("Conexão com o servidor encerrada")


def envia_mensagens(socket_):
    while True:
        msg = input("Msg> ")
        try:
            socket_.sendall(msg.encode("utf-8"))
        except socket.error:
            break
        if msg.lower() == "fim":
            socket_.close()
            break
    print("Envio de mensagens encerrado!")


def client(h, p):

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)  # IPv4,tipo de socket
    s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

    envia = Thread(target=envia_mensagens, args=(s,))
    recebe = Thread(target=recebe_mensagens, args=(s,))

    envia.start()
    recebe.start()

    while threang.active_count() > 1:
        # pausa de 0.1 segundo,
        # Evita que a CPU fique processando a comparação acima sem parar.
        time.sleep(0.1)
    print("Programa encerrado")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    h = input("Host do servidor: ")
    p = input("Porta do servidor: ")
    client(h, p)
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela sua explicação. Consegui resolver esse problema exatamente da maneira que vc mencionou, usando threads, um pra monitorar a chegada de mensagem e outro para controlar o envio delas. 
Na realidade esse programa é um trabalho de faculdade que estou fazendo e é por determinação da professora que utilizo o Python 2. Também estou usando um banco de dados, com o sqlite, no servidor para fazer um sistema de cadastro, autenticação, etc. De fato, o tkinter irá ajudar muito, vou usá-lo em breve.
Novamente, muito obrigado pela resposta.